# Alignment issue with systeme

Tags: systeme

I try to display a low-triangular system of linear equations with systeme using the next code segment

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\sysdelim..
\systeme*{w_1=5,2w_1+w_2=9,-w_1+w_2+w_3=4,2w_1+3w_2+\frac{7}{11}w_3+w_4=2}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

However, the variables are not aligned correctly - for example, the w1's are not in the same column (in other cases there is not problem). Is it possible to figure out what happens? Thanks a lot (i hope that this is not a duplicate question, i did not find something similar in the forum)

Comment: It's `\systeme`, not `\systeme*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*`-variant `\systeme*` flushes right all the right hand sides (it is meant for different cases, such as expressing the solutions of the system).

Just remove the `*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}

\[
\sysdelim..
\systeme{w_1=5,2w_1+w_2=9,-w_1+w_2+w_3=4,2w_1+3w_2+\frac{7}{11}w_3+w_4=2}
\]

\[
\sysdelim..
\systeme*{w_1=5,2w_1+w_2=9,-w_1+w_2+w_3=4,2w_1+3w_2+\frac{7}{11}w_3+w_4=2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]